# Cluster with Windows 7

Tags: window, cluster-computing

Let me keep it simple. I am working in a company on a Software which has a built in auto marking system (Which needs a lot of computer resources). There are Many PCs in my department all with Windows 7 32-Bit and have almost same specs (Same Modal, RAM, Processor). They are connected by LAN Network with 100 Mbps speed. Now i want to make a cluster of computers so i can Run that software on that by utilizing maximum resources of all computers. Is there any special software for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a much faster switch. Because they are limited to 100mbps, you will see a low performance gain if any. Here is a link where there are instructions of how to setup a cluster with Windows. But I recommend getting at least a 1Gbps switch since the nodes will need to send data back and forth to each other. Of course, make sure that the computer's ethernet port supports 1Gbps.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2539.diy-supercomputing-how-to-build-a-small-windows-hpc-cluster.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your feed back sir. But as i said, I have only window 7 on all of my computers with service pack 1. Is there any application or tool available which can create a cluster on window 7 and also having a user friendly Interface...???

Comment: Okay, here is another thread where the answers may be more suited for what you are trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039039/create-a-cluster-of-co-workers-windows-7-pcs-for-parallel-processing-in-r